# Simply Scheme book: "functions.scm", How to use basic language constructs to create interactive prompt for function application

Tags: beginner, reinventing-the-wheel, lisp, scheme, racket

While reading [**Simply Scheme**](https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/%7Ebh/ss-toc2.html) by *Brian Harvey* and *Matthew Wright*:

> [Part I: Chapter 2 Functions](https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/%7Ebh/ssch2/functions.html)

> In this chapter you are going to use the computer to explore functions, but you are *not* going to use the standard Scheme notation as in the rest of the book. That’s
> because, in this chapter, we want to separate the idea of functions from the complexities
> of programming language notation. For example, real Scheme notation lets you write
> expressions that involve more than one function, but in this chapter you can only use
> one at a time.
> To get into this chapter’s special computer interface, first start running Scheme as
> you did in the first chapter, then type `(load "functions.scm")`
> to tell Scheme to read the program you’ll be using. (If you have trouble loading the
> program, look in Appendix A for further information about `load`.) Then, to start the
> program, type
> `(functions)`

I am using DrRacket with `#lang simply-scheme` [Github](https://github.com/jbclements/simply-scheme) [Docs](https://docs.racket-lang.org/manual@simply-scheme/index.html).

So I tried to `(load "functions.scm")` but got this error back:
`open-input-file: cannot open input file path: path/to/functions.scm system error: The system cannot find the file specified.; errid=2`

I also tried `(load "functions.rkt")` and `(require "functions.rkt")`, and got also the same error.

So I read the documentation of `#lang simply-scheme` and found that:

> FIXME: the other helper libraries haven’t been mapped yet. (things like functions.scm would be nice to have as a library.)

So I tried to tackle this problem and implement `(functions)` with my simple racket and scheme experience that I learned from past books.

The notation is interactive and should act like the following:

> You’ll then be able to carry out interactions like the following.* In the text below we’ve
> printed what you type in **boldface** and what the *computer* types in lightface printing:

> Function: **+** 
> Argument: **3** 
> Argument: **5** 
> The result is: 8

> Function: **sqrt** 
> Argument: 144 
> The result is: 12

So here is my code in 2 versions:

First I have defined some helper functions for prompting the user for input:

```lisp
(define (prompt format-string . args)
  (apply printf (cons format-string args))
  (read))

(define (prompt-until pred? input (bad-input (const "")))
  (let ([val (prompt input)])
    (cond [(pred? val) val]
          [else
           (printf (bad-input val))
           (prompt-until pred? input bad-input)])))
```

I also added variadic functions handling, which I think the book version does not support.

*V1*:

```lisp
(define (functions)
  (let ([func-symbol (prompt "Function: ")])
    (with-handlers ([exn:fail:contract:variable? (lambda (_)
                                                   (printf "~a is not defined\n\n" func-symbol)
                                                   (functions))]
                    [exn:fail:contract? (lambda (x)
                                          (printf "\nContract violation ~a\n\n" (regexp-replace
                                                                               #rx": contract violation"
                                                                               (exn-message x)
                                                                               ":"))
                                          (functions))])
      (let* ([function (eval func-symbol)] [arity (procedure-arity function)])
        (let loop ([func (lambda (x) x)] [current-argument 1] [arguments '()] [max-arity arity])
          (cond [(equal? func-symbol 'exit) (printf "exiting (functions)")]
                [(not (procedure? function)) (printf "~a is not a procedure/function\n\n" func-symbol)
                                             (functions)]
                [(and (integer? max-arity) (> current-argument max-arity))
                 (printf "the result is: ~v"
                         (apply function
                                (reverse arguments)))
                 (printf "\n\n")
                 (functions)]
                [(arity-at-least? max-arity)
                 (printf "The functions ~a is varadic and can accept arbitrary number of arguments!\nBut accepts minimum of ~a\n"
                         (symbol->string func-symbol) (arity-at-least-value max-arity))
                 (loop function
                       current-argument
                       arguments
                       (eval (prompt-until exact-nonnegative-integer? "How many argument do you want to supply (Non-negative Integer): ")))]
                [else (loop function
                            (add1 current-argument)
                            (cons (eval (prompt (format "Argument ~a: " current-argument))) arguments)
                            max-arity)]))))))
```

*V2*:
Here I removed some `let` bindings and tried to quit early when an abnormal case happens so the recursion doesn't have to expensive with all the checks happening each time.

I also added more checks for variadic arity count.

I also used a `for/list` comprehension instead of a hand-made tail recursive loop.

```lisp
(define (functions)
  (let ([func-symbol (prompt "Function: ")])
    (with-handlers ([exn:fail:contract:variable? (lambda (_)
                                                   (printf "~a is not defined.\n\n" func-symbol)
                                                   (functions))]
                    [exn:fail:contract? (lambda (x)
                                          (printf "Contract violation ~a\n\n" (regexp-replace
                                                                               #rx": contract violation"
                                                                               (exn-message x)
                                                                               ":"))
                                          (functions))])
      (cond [(member? func-symbol '(exit quit)) (displayln "exiting (functions)")]
            [else
             (let ([function (eval func-symbol)])
               (cond
                 [(not (procedure? function)) (printf "~a is not a procedure/function\n\n" function)
                                              (functions)]
                 [else
                  (let* ([arity (procedure-arity function)]
                         [integer-arity (cond [(arity-at-least? arity)
                                               (printf "The function ~a is varadic and can accept arbitrary number of arguments!\nBut accepts minimum of ~a\n"
                                                       function (arity-at-least-value arity))
                                               (prompt-until (conjoin exact-nonnegative-integer?
                                                                      (curry <= (arity-at-least-value arity)))
                                                             (format "How many argument do you want to supply (Non-negative Integer >= ~a): "
                                                                     (arity-at-least-value arity)))]
                                              [(integer? arity) arity])]
                         [arguments (for/list ([i (in-range 1 (add1 integer-arity))])
                                      (eval (prompt "Argument ~a: " i)))])
                    (printf "Result is: ~v\n\n"
                            (apply function arguments))
                    (functions))]))]))))
```

I have played with this function and it seems to work normally in all cases as it does handle abnormal cases correctly by printing the errors and not showing the errors directly to the end-user.

I didn't handle all `procedure-arity` cases; because I thought it was sufficient handling normal functions and simple variadic functions only.

My major concerns are:

- Using 3 `let`s.
- Using 3 `cond`s.
- The code contains many levels of deep nesting.

I think my code is rather long, fairly unreadable, and for that I apologize.

Also I would like to know if I'm violating any major conventions of the language in any obvious ways.

I am sorry for the lengthy question, but I wanted to present all the background details, and I wanted to follow the [StackExchange Code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com) Guide as much as I can.

Pardon me for any writing mistakes; English is not my mother tongue.

Thanks in advance.